# Processing successors in dfs with Haskell

Tags: haskell, depth-first-search, fold

Consider the following Python function, which, given the successors of a node, visits them and collects the results. (In practice this logic would form a part of the recursive `visit` function.)

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Tuple, List, Set
Node_key = Any
Discovered = Set[Node_key]
Result = Any

def get_successor_results(visit: Callable[[Discovered, Node_key], 
                                          Tuple[Discovered, Result]],
                          successors: List[Node_key],
                          disc: Discovered) -> List[Result]:
    results = []
    for succ in successors:
        if succ not in disc:
            disc, result = visit(disc, succ)
            results.append(result)
    return results
```

(For context, this would be part of a df-traverse function which, given a graph and a function `combiner :: Node_key -> [Result] -> Result` would be equivalent to building the depth-first forest and calling `fold-tree combiner` on each tree.)

> **My Question:** How would you write `get_successor_results` in Haskell?

Some ideas:

```hask
get-successor-results visit successors disc = 
  reverse . first . conditional-fold 
                      (\(d, _) node -> not (elem node d))
                      (cons-next-result visit)
                      (empty-set, [])
                      successors
  where
    cons-next-result visit _@(disc, results) node =
      let (disc-new, result) = visit disc node
      in (disc-new, result:results)
    conditional-fold p folder e xs = case xs of 
      {[] -> e;
       x:xs' -> if p e x then conditional-fold p folder (folder e x) xs'
                else conditional-fold p folder e xs'}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks pretty straightforward to translate it directly:

```haskell
get_successor_results ::
    (node_key -> discovered -> Bool) ->
    (node_key -> State discovered result) ->
    [node_key] ->
    State discovered [result]
get_successor_results not_in visit successors = do
    results <- for successors $ \succ -> do
        should_visit <- gets (succ `not_in`)
        if should_visit
            then Just <$> visit succ
            else return Nothing
    return (catMaybes results)
```

Hopefully the parallels with your Python code are clear. The only real twist here is to use `Nothing` as a placeholder for successors you don't want to visit and strip them away as a second step. Of course, I recommend that you use camel-case names; that's a strong convention in Haskell, so it will blend in better with existing library calls, but I wanted the parallels to be as obvious as possible so I used the same names as your Python code wherever possible.

Comment: Interesting that some functions seem to want to be written imperatively. I wonder what distinguishes them. Perhaps one feature is that they want a lot of shared state between their components (like shared state between stack frames, for instance). Have you encountered any writing on this?

Comment: @EricAuld I think some authors seem to want to write imperatively. This is absolutely not how I would do a DFS. See the excellent paper [Inductive Graphs and Functional Graph Algorithms](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/abstracts.html#JFP01) for alternatives.

Comment: Do you see people attempting this destructuring approach outside of Erwig's library? It seems possible in principle to do it with an ordinary adjacency representation, deleting edges and nodes as you go. Persistent data structures could help it not consume so much space.